# How to to get custom return value from system()

Tags: linux, return-value

I need to pass 1 value between programs. In my case, I run (VERY SIMPLE) program within another by calling system("SimpleProgram").

Is there a way how to pass 1 value (integer) returned by SimpleProgram. Neither "return 123" nor "exit(123)" doesnt work.

Is there any elegant way to pass such value? (I dont want to write and read an external file)

EDIT:

The language is C++, the programming is done on BeagleBone with Angstrom distribution.

retCode = system("cd /home/martin/uart/temp/xml_parser && ./xmldom");

Comment: Which language do you use? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what the man page for `system(3)` says about the return code:

> The  value  returned is -1 on error (e.g.  fork(2) failed), and the
>   return status of the command otherwise.
>          This latter return status is in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the  command  will
>          be  WEXITSTATUS(status).

So you're almost there. If you have a simple program that returns 123, as you stated:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return 123;
}
```

then you can run it with `system(3)` and see its return code by using `WEXITSTATUS()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int rc = system(argv[1]);
    cout << WEXITSTATUS(rc) << '\n';
}
```

Naming the first program `return123` and the second `system`:

```
$ ./system ./return123
123
```

If you leave off the `WEXITSTATUS()` and just print `rc` directly, you will get an incorrect value.

Comment: Except this likely cannot be used. Return values are only in 0-255 range, so that's already small. Part of this range denotes standard errors, so if a legal value also matches an error code you have to do crap dancing with offseting all values, but it may be you can't. I strongly suggest that op reads manpages better, familiarizes himself with popen(3) and makes the tool print stuff instead.

Comment: Well, the OP said that's all he wanted-- to pass the exit value from a simple command back to the invoker. Sometimes that's all you need.

Comment: The OP had weird trouble using system(3). One has to assume he was not aware of range limitation and did not consider error/val overlap.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is with UNIX pipes.

If it's just a hack, you might as well just use the binary return value, but in either case, you'd have to use execve() instead of system().